# .click() для элементов загруженным с помощью ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

есть функция jquery, которая не работает на элементы `div.img-page`

```
$('.clickable > div.img-page').on('click', function () {
$(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').find('> div.img-page.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

элементы `div.img-page` загружаются с помощью `ajax`. **НО ЕСЛИ ЗАГРУЖАТЬ ЭТИ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ НЕ `AJAX`'ом, А ПРИ ЗАГРУЗКИ СТРАНИЦЫ ТО ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ.** Как исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).on('click','.clickable > div.img-page', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').find('> div.img-page.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: вы вообще гений никодаб не додумался до такого сидел часов 10 ине мог дошадаться

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickable > div.img-page').live('click', function () {
$(this).addClass('active').parents('.clickable').find('> div.img-page.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
Источник: http://jquery-docs.ru/events/live/
```

Comment: Забудьте про live(), это уже история.